# Formulierungshilfe Satz

Tags: sentence-structure

Mir fällt gerade nichts Vernünftiges ein.

Ich müsste einen Satz so formulieren, dass er das ausdrückt, was ich meine.

> Von Gerät zu Gerät sind unterschiedliche Komponenten verbaut.

Ausdrücken möchte ich, dass Geräte teils dieselben, aber trotzdem noch andere, teils aber auch komplett andere Komponenten verbaut haben können.

Vorschläge?

Comment: "In den Geräten ist jeweils eine Auswahl von Komponenten verbaut, die sich teilweise überschneiden" - Das kommt für mich aber ziemlich stark auf den Kontext an, und inwiefern der Leser weiss, was eine Komponente ist, welche Möglichen Komponenten es gibt und so weiter.

Comment: @tannerli da stimme ich dir zu, und deine Lösung finde ich super, mir haben eure Ansätze jetzt geholfen, es in meine Fachsprache zu übersetzen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- > In den Geräten sind Komponenten verbaut, welche sich teilweise unterscheiden können.
- > Die in den Geräten verbauten Komponenten unterscheiden sich teilweise.
- > Die in den Geräten verbauten Komponenten können sich teilweise unterscheiden.

Comment: dankeschön ;) ist manchmal schwer die richtigen Worte zu finden, wenn man schon ne Zeit lang schreibt :)

Comment: Satz 1: Wenn die Geräte sich nicht unterscheiden würden wären die Komponenten nicht unterschiedlich, so dass der zweite Teilsatz befremdlich wirkt. "In den Geräten sind zum Teil unterschiedliche Komponenten verbaut." würde ausdrücken, dass nicht alle unterschiedlich sind.